# Introduce api level and Manifest

Tags: android

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html
in this guide write that introduced in API level 9.

Will it work when minSdkVersion = 8 and targetSdkVersion > 11 in Manifest.xml?

Answer (score 2):

It was introduced in API 9, so it won't work on devices using level 8, but will work on devices using >=9

Answer (score 1):

it wont work on 8. To change the manifest do:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not work when you are using api level 8 Devies .it will work in api level 9 or above devices. But you have to change the android library to 2.3 or higher for compilation.

**Android Library for Compiling**

[image: For Compilation Android Library]

**In Manifest**

`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>`